# How to find business days between dates with Pandas CDay?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I've defined a Pandas `CDay()` object which stores the holidays. How can I use that to find the number of business days between two dates?

I'm aware of `np.busday_count`, but my calendar happens to be that Pandas `CDay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass your week mask and holidays from the `CDay` calendar directly to [`np.busday_count`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidyYCwxtbSAhVpxYMKHVRoAWoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.1%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.busday_count.html&usg=AFQjCNGteBEjCJRNnd9VlOTUmJMhWKArqg).

```
np.busday_count(start_date, end_date,
                weekmask=bday_custom.weekmask, holidays=bday_custom.holidays)
```

Alternatively (but certainly slower), you can use [`pd.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.date_range.html), and pass your custom `CDay` calendar as the `freq`.

```
pd.date_range(datetime(2017, 3, 5), datetime(2017, 3, 12), freq=bday_cust).size
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect of creating an intermediary date range only to use its size.

---

**Example**

Let's set up a meaningless custom business day calendar.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
weekmask = 'Mon Wed Fri Sat'
holidays = [datetime(2017, 3, 6), datetime(2017, 3, 11)]

bday_cust = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays, weekmask=weekmask)
```

Now we've set the Monday and the Saturday to be business days (and holidays) for the week of March 5th to 11th. Now looking at that particular date range, we can count the remaining business days (2)

```
>>> np.busday_count(datetime(2017, 3, 5), datetime(2017, 3, 12),
                    weekmask=bday_custom.weekmask, 
                    holidays=bday_custom.holidays)
2
>>> pd.date_range(datetime(2017, 3, 5), datetime(2017, 3, 12), freq=bday_cust).size
2
```

**Rough benchmark on example**

```
%timeit np.busday_count(datetime(2017, 3, 5), datetime(2017, 3, 12),
                        weekmask=bday_custom.weekmask, 
                        holidays=bday_custom.holidays)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 us per loop

% timeit pd.date_range(datetime(2017, 3, 5), datetime(2017, 3, 12), freq=bday_cust).size
1000 loops, best of 3: 573 us per loop
```